# Using Scipy's signal.welch command on data: ValueError and a dimension mismatch?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to get my first power spectral density graph plotted using actual data instead of something that's purely theoretical and generated within Python.  I'm having problems getting anything to work, however. Code is attached below, followed by the error I get in my console after line 19.

Don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm transitioning to Python from mostly working in MATLAB. I am not counting on having access to a license forever, so I really want to learn how to start doing everything in Python. But it's hard.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import data from a .mat file using the loadmat command
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('Mic_Data_Sums.mat')

# 1 x 1 array, sampling frequency of 22050 Hz
fs = mat['Fs']

# Attempted fix: change data type to 8-point float?
# fs = fs.astype('f8')

# 13 x 1323000 array - 13 separate time series of data, 60 seconds each
data = mat['Mic_Data_Sums']

# Welch function - transpose 'data' and use the 2nd time series
f, Pxx_spec = signal.welch(data.T[1], fs, window = 'hanning', nperseg = fs,
    noverlap = fs/2, scaling = 'spectrum')
```

**Console:**

```
/Users/******/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py:297: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  scale = 1.0 / win.sum()**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotPSDs.py", line 20, in <module>
    noverlap = fs/2, scaling = 'spectrum')
  File "/Users/******/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 333, in welch
    xft = fftpack.rfft(x_dt*win, nfft)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (22050,) (0,22051)
```

Note how the ValueError tag gives me weird shape (dimension) results: I have no idea where the 22051 is coming from.

**Edit:** As a workaround solution, I commented out the line of `fs = mat['Fs']` and simply replaced it with `fs = 22050`, which made the code execute successfully. However, the question still remains, why can't I simply reference the variable as it was stored in the .mat file?

Comment: Would you be able to upload your data somewhere so we can reproduce the problem?  I'd like to be able to do it on my end and diagnose.

Comment: Maybe? I don't really know the best way to go about it because the file is quite large (66.8 MB).  However, I found that if I just change the one variable to an outright integer (that I don't get from the .mat file) it works fine. There is something I'm not understanding about variable types and how I should use loadmat.

Comment: If you know `fs` is 1x1, try passing `fs[0,0]` to `welch`.  The docstring for `welch` says `fs` should be a float, so it might behave unpredictably if you give it a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

[from the comments above] If you know `fs` is 1x1, try passing `fs[0,0]` to `welch`. The docstring for `welch` says `fs` should be a float, so it might behave unpredictably if you give it a two-dimensional array. –  Warren Weckesser 22 hours ago

This worked well. The code I implemented is:

```
# 1 x 1 array, sampling frequency (22050 Hz)
fs = mat['Fs']
fs = fs[0,0]
```

then using the code from before,

```
f, Pxx_spec = signal.welch(data.T[1], fs, window = 'hanning', nperseg = fs,
noverlap = fs/2, scaling = 'spectrum')
```